# NLOC and Complexity numbers during Code Analysis

Tags: c++14

I wrote a code for constructing an  expression tree and traversing the tree in three different ways
a) Inorder traversal
b) Postorder Traversal
c) Level order Traversal

So, I wanted to know the complexity of my code and found this website which calculates it:
 [ http://www.lizard.ws/ ]

These were the results:

```
Function Name       NLOC      Complexity     Token #    Parameter #  

faw                  10         6             51    
push                 12         2             61    
pushp                12         2             61    
pop                   5         1             25    
popp                  5         1             25    
inorder               9         2             38    
postorder             9         2             38    
printLevelOrder       7         2             40    
printLevel           12         4             66    
height               15         3             76    
main                 100        21           738
```

**Question:**
What does NLOC and the numbers for complexity denote? Does having a high number mean, the code isn't well optimized?

Comment: The source code is [here](https://github.com/terryyin/lizard).  See for yourself.

Comment: I'm sure NLOC and complexity numbers has nothing to do with the source code of the analyzer.

Comment: Well, the source code is going to dictate how the website calculates these numbers.  Ergo, the manner in which the numbers are interpreted must be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

NLOC Denotes number of lines of code.For example here against push function the value is 12,NLOC tell us the size of function.Complexity column denotes the complexity of each function code.